# Hide content after 3 paragraphs <p>

Tags: javascript, jquery, formatting

Working with an API that spits out the contents in p tags ... but it gets too long. Thinking of hiding them upon reaching a limit of 400 characters, but that's not a good idea since there is a possibility of it cutting through a HTML tag.

So I'm trying to hide the rest of the content after 3 paragraphs instead and with a text "Read More" that will unhide the rest of the content. How would one accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div><p></p><p></p><p></p><p></p><p></p>
    <a href="#readMore" class="readMore">Read More</a>
</div>
```

if you have this kind of structure, you can

```
$('div p:nth-child(3)').nextAll('p').hide();
```

and

```
$('a.readMore').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings('p').show();
    return false;
})
```

resources:
 - [.nextAll()](http://api.jquery.com/nextall/)

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [`:gt() selector`](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) and then [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide) or [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove) them:

```
var $content = $("#content");
$content.find("p:gt(2)").hide();
```

Or you could just hide all children elements beyond the third using [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children) and [`.slice(3)`](http://api.jquery.com/slice):

```
$content.children().slice(3).hide();
```

If you store the hidden elements you can even create your read more button very easily:

```
var $content = $("#content");
var $hiddenText = $content.children().slice(3).hide();
if ($hiddenText.length) {       
    var $button = $("<a href='#'>Read More...</a>").click(function() {
        $hiddenText.show();
        $button.remove();
        return false;
    }).appendTo($content);
}
```

[View jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gnarf/XmDxb/)

Answer (score 0):

This is slightly a backwards approach but do something like this.

```
<style>
#con p{
  display:none;
}
</style>

<div id='con'>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Then have jquery select the first three p tags and set the display to block.

Also, you could use

```
<style>
#con{
  overflow:auto;
  max-height:300px;
}
</style>
```

And you wouldn't have to worry about any of it.

Comment: the problem with this is if javascript is disbled, you can't show what is hidden. So better hide things with jQuery then show it when needed.. ;)